# Pathfinder Office not carrier correcting my data

Tags: pathfinder, post-processing

I'm having an odd/frustrating issue with PFO. Specifically, I have not been able to correctly post-process any data for months.

To elaborate, my coworkers are all able to post-process the same SSF with 100% carrier correction, but my system fails (0% carrier correction).

Using the exact same file and post-processing settings, I get the following:

```
Differential Correction Summary:
1 file processed.  In this file:
    576 (100.00%) of 576 selected positions were code corrected by post-processing
    0 (0.00%) of 576 selected positions were carrier corrected by post-processing

Estimated accuracies for 576 corrected positions are as follows:
        Range   Percentage
        ----------  ----------
          0-5cm      -
         5-15cm      -
        15-30cm      -
        30-50cm      -
         0.5-1m 21.70%
           1-2m 70.31%
           2-5m  7.99%
            >5m      -
```

My coworkers (who all are using the same PFO version and server license) use the exact same settings and get the following:

```
Differential Correction Summary:
1 file processed.  In this file:
    576 (100.00%) of 576 selected positions were code corrected by post-processing
    576 (100.00%) of 576 selected positions were carrier corrected by post-processing

Estimated accuracies for 576 corrected positions are as follows:
        Range   Percentage
        ----------  ----------
          0-5cm      -
         5-15cm 100.00%
        15-30cm      -
        30-50cm      -
         0.5-1m      -
           1-2m      -
           2-5m      -
            >5m      -
```

Pathfinder Office version:5.65

Terrasync version:5.30

Handheld unit: GeoXH 6000

External antenna: Trimble Tornado

Comment: Do you know what base station you are using?  If your colleagues are using a different base station with a shorter base line then they could get carrier correction and you might not.

Comment: Thanks for responding. We all used the same base stations (have tried multiple base stations) with the same results.

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange problem - I do a lot of work with PFO and have not come across this before.  I have three suggestions:

- First, check that your PFO installation has all available updates.  If you run PFO and go to Help / Check for new GPS Pathfinder Updates now. . . , (then close PFO), you'll get a list of available updates.
- Second, if the first suggestion doesn't help, run the Differential Correction Wizard, and check that Processing type is set to "Automatic Carrier and Code processing" (yes, I know you said your PC's PFO settings are the same as on your colleague's machines. . . )
- Third, if the first and second suggestions don't help, you could try to uninstall PFO 5.65 then reinstall it.