# Pathfinder office (ssf) to ArcGIS (shp) projection issue in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps

I'm honestly not sure if that's even the problem but here's what's going on:

Collected points with Trimble Geo7X set to NAD83 UTM zone 15N. Post-processed the points in Pathfinder Office, transformed to a shapefile and opened in ArcMap. There was some issue there where I had to open in ArcCatalog and set the projection again.

The points seemed to display correctly in ArcMap at first, but when I added a TIF as background imagery it was clear that they were in the wrong spot. I used Calculate Geometry to see the coordinates and they were correct but in decimal degrees.
Ex. (-93.652034, 42.031155). If I use Identify, the coordinates are different and in dms (97 29'22.498", 0 0'1.365") for the same point. Seems like they displayed in the wrong projection and coordinate system but I'm not sure how.
Adding the correction summaries:

```
Differential Correction Summary:
    1 file processed.  In this file:
        1164 (100.00%) of 1164 selected positions were code corrected by post-processing
        1163 (99.91%) of 1164 selected positions were carrier corrected by post-processing

    Estimated accuracies for 1164 corrected positions are as follows:
            Range   Percentage
            ----------  ----------
              0-5cm 99.66%
             5-15cm  0.26%
            15-30cm      -
            30-50cm      -
             0.5-1m      -
               1-2m  0.09%
               2-5m      -
                >5m      -

Differential correction complete.

Differential Correction Summary:
    1 file processed.  In this file:
        3585 (99.97%) of 3586 selected positions were code corrected by post-processing
        1422 (39.65%) of 3586 selected positions were carrier corrected by post-processing
        1252 (88.05%) of code positions chosen over carrier, as they were of higher quality

    Estimated accuracies for 3585 corrected positions are as follows:
            Range   Percentage
            ----------  ----------
              0-5cm      -
             5-15cm  0.59%
            15-30cm  0.31%
            30-50cm  0.11%
             0.5-1m 20.22%
               1-2m 63.26%
               2-5m 14.28%
                >5m  1.23%

Differential correction complete.
```

Comment: Do you have the Pathfinder summary? like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224161/pathfinder-office-not-carrier-correcting-my-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pathfinder Office may have done the post-processing in 15N, but didn't export the points in 15N. There may be a setting that you can change for this.

Use the Define Projection Tool to set the coordinate system to EPSG::4269 in ArcGIS.

Comment: Thanks, apparently PO was set to a different projection, so I changed it and problem solved!